# Move files into separate subfolders

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I've been trying to write a shell script for a while and am just stumped. I'm on a mac and have some knowledge of using UNIX but I'm stumped. I have a list of files:

```
folder1_123
folder1_abc
folder2_654
folder2_zxy
```

and I want them to be like this:

```
folder1/123
folder1/abc
folder2/654
folder2/zxy
```

so far I've gotten a script that looks like this:

```
for file in *_.*; do
dir=${file%%.*}
mkdir -p "$dir"
mv "$file" "$dir"
done
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current script?

Comment: You want to create empty files in the name `123`, `abc`, `654` and `zxy`? or the files exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below one liner script for the same. Run this script in the directory containing all files in the format *_*. It will iterate over each file name will take first part before _ and will create a directory with that name.After that it will move the file from parent directory to newly created directory,until its done with all files.

```
for i in `ls |grep _`;do mkdir -p `echo $i|cut -f1 -d "_"`;mv $i `echo $i|cut -f1 -d "_"`/`echo $i|cut -f2 -d "_"`;done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split file/dir name with 'cut':

```
for file in *_*; do
  DIRNAME=$(echo $file | cut -d"_" -f1)
  if [[ ! -d ${DIRNAME} ]]; then
    mkdir ${DIRNAME}
  fi
  FILENAME=$(echo $file | cut -d"_" -f2)
  mv $file ${DIRNAME}/${FILENAME}
done
```

Comment: This will not work when the files `123`, `abc`, `654` and `zxy` are not present for `mv` to move. It is not clear from the OP at this point of time if an empty file has to be created or the original files do exist.

Comment: Didn't mean the answer to be faulty, but just that, for a file `folder1_123`, your script will create a new folder `folder1` if it doesn't exists(should have been `mkdir -p`) and the file `123` should have been present in the current folder for it to be copied to `folder1`. `mv` will crib stating `no such file..` when you attempt to move a non-existent file. That is why stated that it is not clear if an empty file needs to be created for which OP hasn't responded yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The body of your loop is wrong. It should be:

```
dir=${file%_*}
newfn=${file#*_}
mkdir -p $dir && mv $file $dir/$newfn
```

Depending on your requirements, you might or might not want to add a guard

```
if [[ -f $file ]]
then
   ...
fi
```

around this.